# Bootstrap 3 Navbar Toggle Dropdown

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3

I really seem to struggle with the "boostrap navigation bar" not sure why, I read through documentation several times, but I struggle regardless. That being said I am perplexed on what is going on here.

I am creating a wordpress theme using Bootstrap 3. The Toggle Dropdown using the class=sr-only is showing on navbar.

Here is the screenshot: http://prntscr.com/j2xsab

How do I hide this, or what is this for exacly?

```
<!--====NAVBAR====-->
        <div class="container"><!-- Container -->
            <div class="align">
                <div class="row"><!-- Row -->
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top col-md-10 text-left">
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </button>
                            <!--<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>-->
                            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse ">
                            <?php wp_nav_menu( array(
                                'theme_location'    => 'main_menu',
                                'container'         => 'nav active',
                                'container_class'   => 'navbar-collapse collapse',
                                'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right'

                                ) );
                            ?>
                            </div><!-- Collapse -->
                        </div><!-- Navbar Header -->
                    </nav><!-- Main Navigation -->
                </div><!-- Row -->
            </div><!-- Align -->
        </div><!-- Container -->
```

Comment: ["screen readers only"](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/#skip-navigation)

Comment: Are you linking to the Bootstrap CSS file? Do you get any 404 errors in the console?

Comment: Thank you for reply. I have played around with it some more. You can see it here https://theord.com - I am not getting a responsive site and I am unsure why. @Blazemonger I believe (I could be wrong) that the .navbar-collapse is the class that makes this responsive happen. I have that in my code. I also believe that navigation.js which I have linked also able to help. Here is a screenshot http://prntscr.com/j3wtzr